# gradle project import failure

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am trying to import an gradle project into my eclipse but facing some error,

I am adding the screenshot below
[image]

please help me sort out the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems it cannot allocate enough memory to start the daemon process. Can you try increasing the heap size of the JVM?

This webpage shows you how to increase Eclipse's heap size:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F